# How to make an object a solid color in the Krunker Editor?

Tags: krunker-editor

I have the following map with a cube setup using the default setup.

[image: Cube with Stone Texture]

However, as you can see, it has a stone texture on it.  I want a pure blue cube.  So, I changed the style option on the right sidebar to make its color value be `#0000FF`.

[image: Editor Screenshot of Blue Cube with Stone Texture]

Again, though, the cube still has the stone texture.  Is there a way to make the cube be a solid color?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is not related to programming

Answer (score 0):

You can set the texture type of the cube to be `default` to make it be a solid color.  This setting's location is `style > texture > type`.  Here's the fixed cube screenshot which includes the location of where to change the texture of the cube.

[image: Editor Screenshot]